# How to remove "comments_like_dislike" function by remove_action hook?

Tags: wordpress

I have tried below code:

```
remove_filter("comment_text",array("CLD_Comments_Hooks","comments_like_dislike"),200,2);
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: disable the plugin? :)

Answer (score 0):

Within a child themes functions.php file add:

```
add_filter( 'init', 'remove_my_action');
function remove_my_action() { 
    remove_filter("comment_text",array("CLD_Comments_Hooks","comments_like_dislike"),200,2);
}
```

Ref: [remove_action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. I added this code in "Twenty Seventeen" version 1.7 main theme. but it's not worked.I want to apply on main theme, so i added your suggestion on main theme function.php
I can't disable the plugin because i want used plugin functionality and replace the plugin function with my custom function with the help of hook.
i just want to replace plugin function with my custom function so i just want to replce plugin hook and then add my custom function with this hook.

Comment: Yes i have update the code and test more than one time.